# iOS Top Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Which is the best approach in order to create a Top Navigation Bar like this one on Instagram?

I have a Tab Bar controller which has 5 views but I do not understand how to create another navigation bar inside one of this views. Should I create two labels and connect each of them with another view or is there something better to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is good, would be nice to see some screenshots or code to fully understand it.

If you want to put navigation bar inside those tab bar views you need to put a container view that connects to a navigation controller.

I created a [simple project](https://github.com/karlolopez/iOSTopNavigationTabBarExample) to show you how I achieved this.

Using a scrollview to contain another two view containers embedded with some navigation controllers:

[image]

The view containers allows you to embed any type of view / controller:

[image]

[Apple docs has a nice reference of how to do this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html), in your case you just need to change ViewController to NavigationController.

And if you don't mind to use third party code, well there are plenty of options for you to choose:

[**PolioPager**](https://github.com/YuigaWada/PolioPager)

```
import PolioPager

class ViewController: MainContainerViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func tabItems()-> [TabItem] {
        return [TabItem(title: "One"),TabItem(title: "Two")]
    }

    override func viewControllers()-> [UIViewController]
    {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let viewController1 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "cont1")
        let viewController2 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "cont2")

        return [viewController1, viewController2]
    }
}
```

In above example you can use PolioPager to instantiate 2 different navigation view controllers, identified by storyboard identifier `cont1` `cont2` for example.

Other trip party libraries:

https://github.com/XuYanci/GLViewPagerController

https://github.com/rechsteiner/Parchment

Comment: I'm not into third party code but thanks for the advice, can u explain a little more in detail what do u mean by "put a container view that connects to a navigation controller" ?

Comment: Check my updated answer, created a quick example of how to achieve it: https://github.com/karlolopez/iOSTopNavigationTabBarExample

Comment: wow this is exactly what I was looking for. So lets say the container hosts one ore more navigation controllers (which then connects to a view controller) right?

Comment: one more question: If i scroll to the first view to 30% lets say and then i go to the second view a d I scroll to 50% ,,, later if I go back to the first view will it be still at 30% or it will be reseted to 0%? so my concern is.. will it preserve the state?

Comment: Yes a container hosts a single navigation controller. In the example im putting 2 of those containers inside a scrollview.

Comment: The states will preserve as they are individual instances and completely independent.